# Bootstrap img to the right doesn't work, display none too

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[image]

This is how looks my navbar. My problem is that the right img is not completely to the right. Img on the left is on the left exactly like I want. What is wrong? I tryed to add style do img of second div: text align right but It doesnt work. 
Here is code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="float: left" >
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 text-center" style="float: left">
            <div class="navbar-text">Lorem ipsum 
       Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem 
       ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 text-left" style="float: left">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use the class `pull-right` if you can create a plunker to reproduce it will be great

Comment: what is plunker?

Comment: Live editor for js frameworks [**see here**](https://plnkr.co/)

Comment: I tryed to add pull-right but still not working -to my class with cols where is second img instead text-left :/

Comment: Someone know solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-2" >
             <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty0.png">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8 text-center">
             <div class="navbar-text">Lorem ipsum 
   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem 
   ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xs-2">
            <img style="float:right;" class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty1.png">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:center;" >
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty0.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 text-center" style="float: left">
            <div class="navbar-text">Lorem ipsum 
       Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  Lorem 
       ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="text-align:center;">
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Brand" src="buty1.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```